# CheckMarx issue Heap_Inspection for PasswordBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, passwordbox, checkmarx

I'm struck with an issue with Checkmarx.

My application is built in WPF with C# coding. Below is the XAML for the PasswordBox

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="pwdPassword"
Controls:PasswordBoxHelper.CapsLockWarningToolTip="True" 
Controls:PasswordBoxHelper.CapsLockIcon="CAPSLOCK IS ON"
Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Password" 
HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Margin="121,144,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253"/>
```

This is used to check the user against Active Directory and I'm using the below code to authenticate

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DomainName"))
 {
bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(txtUsername.Text, ADMIN.ConvertToUnsecureString(pwdPassword.SecurePassword), ContextOptions.Negotiate);
pwdPassword=null;

if (isValid)
 {
 //Open the application
}
else
{
//Display message and quit.
}
```

The application works perfect but when I scan this with Checkmarx I get the below Heap_Inspection issue.

**> Method VerticalAlignment="Top"/> at line 19 of \Test1\MainWindow.xaml defines pwdPassword, which is designated to contain user passwords. However, while plaintext passwords are later assigned to pwdPassword, this variable is never cleared from memory.**

I've set the pwdPassword to null as soon as i'm done with it, yet i get the error. I've also used the below finally block to collect the garbage

```
finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
```

Could someone please help me on how to clear it from the memory.

Much appreciated.

---------********************* Further Progress ****************-------------

I've made the below changes and assuming that the plain password is not saved to a variable but yet no success

```
using System.Security;
using System.Windows;
namespace Stack
{
    public static class PasswordBoxMVVMAttachedProperties
    {
        public static SecureString GetEncryptedPassword(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (SecureString)obj.GetValue(EncryptedPasswordProperty);
        }
        public static void SetEncryptedPassword(DependencyObject obj, SecureString value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(EncryptedPasswordProperty, value);
        }
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for EncryptedPassword. This enables animation, styling, binding, etc... 
        public static readonly DependencyProperty EncryptedPasswordProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("EncryptedPassword", typeof(SecureString), typeof(PasswordBoxMVVMAttachedProperties));
    }
}
```

The Xaml has been changed to

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="pwdPassword" local:PasswordBoxMVVMAttachedProperties.EncryptedPassword="{Binding PasswordSecureString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Controls:PasswordBoxHelper.CapsLockWarningToolTip="True" Controls:PasswordBoxHelper.CapsLockIcon="CAPSLOCK IS ON" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Password" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,144,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253" PasswordChanged="pwdPassword_PasswordChanged"/>
```

and the code behind PasswordChanged is below

```
private void pwdPassword_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     pwdPassword = sender as PasswordBox;
Stack.PasswordBoxMVVMAttachedProperties.SetEncryptedPassword(pwdPassword, pwdPassword.SecurePassword);
    }
```

The login button has the below code

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAINNAME"))
     {
bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(txtUsername.Text,
ADMIN.ConvertToUnsecureString(Stack.PasswordBoxMVVMAttachedProperties.GetEncryptedPassword(pwdPassword)), ContextOptions.Negotiate);
              //              pwdPassword = null;
if (isValid == true)
{
//Open Application
}
else
{
//Quit Application
}
}
```

Despite this, i get the same error. Could someone please double check and help me find where am I missing anything, if I am.

Any help will be much appreciated.

**Latest Update :07/12/2017**

I've zeroed the issue to it's root cause.

I've created a WPF with just a PasswordBox (No code behind) and scanned it against CheckMarx and getting the same error (Please find the attached picture.)
[image: Checkmarx Screenshot]

Comment: The PasswordBox will be eligible for garbage collection as soon as the view is. Of course it will remain in memory as long as the view lives because it is part of the view.

Comment: @mm8 Thank you for your input but somehow i need to address this issue.

Comment: Setting it to null isn't the same as clearing it.  Clearing it is clearing it.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.clear(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: pwdPassword.Clear();
    pwdPassword =null;
Still no Luck

Comment: There is no issue to be sorted out if your view is not unloaded.

Comment: I am also stuck on a similar issue with CheckMarx:

Method <asp:textbox id="tbxPassword" runat="server" CssClass="tbxStyle_t" Enabled="False" TextMode="Password"></asp:textbox> at line 348 of CARPRO_V_Upgradation/EditUserInformation.aspx defines tbxPassword, which is designated to contain user passwords. However, while plaintext passwords are later assigned to tbxPassword, this variable is never cleared from memory.